# Using Rownum in Cursor Bulk Collect Oracle

Tags: oracle, cursor, rownum, forall, bulk-collect

I'm trying to use the rownum to simulate a column autonumbered as I need to use it as an ID. Since it is an ID, I look at the final table if no record with MAX (ID).
The problem I have is when I want to do arithmetic operations within the cursor or when you invoke, or when you want to use a function. The ROWNUM (v_id) field is empty me when I want to print with DBMS_OUTPUT . Anyone have any idea how to solve it without using sequences ?
Here put the sample code.

```
declare

  max_id number;
  CURSOR INSRT(w_max number) IS
  SELECT f_max_fact_sap(to_number(V_ID),w_max) AS V_ID,Seriei,serief
  FROM (SELECT To_Char(ROWNUM) AS V_ID, A.*
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.matnr, a.seriei, a.serief,a.xblnr,a.fecha_sap, ((SERIEF-SERIEI)+1) AS rango
                  FROM SOPFUN.TT_ZMOVIMI_FACTURADAS a
                WHERE 0 =(SELECT COUNT(1)
                            FROM PA_ZMOVIMI_FACTURADAS B
                            WHERE A.SERIEI = B.SERIEI
                              AND A.SERIEF = B.SERIEF
                              AND A.MATNR = B.MATNR
                              AND A.FECHA_SAP=B.FECHA_SAP)
                    AND A.FECHA_SAP IS NOT NULL) A);
  TYPE T_INSRT IS TABLE OF INSRT%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  V_INSRT T_INSRT;


begin
  SELECT Max(Nvl(ID,10000)) INTO MAX_ID-- To Proof because the table is empty
    FROM PA_ZMOVIMI_FACTURADAS;

OPEN INSRT(MAX_ID);
    LOOP
    FETCH INSRT BULK COLLECT INTO V_INSRT LIMIT 1000;
        FOR I IN 1 .. V_INSRT.Count loop
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: ' ||V_INSRT(I).V_ID||' SI: '||V_INSRT(I).SERIEI||' SI: '||V_INSRT(I).SERIEF||' OPERACION: '||to_char(f_max_fact_sap(V_INSRT(I).V_ID,MAX_ID)));
        end loop;        
    EXIT WHEN INSRT%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: It seems likely that the issue is in the `f_max_fact_sap` function, which provides the ultimate value for the `V_ID` column.

Comment: This function in what I do is add the value of the max_id rownum . I tried it with the function and directly by the ( max_id + rownum ) but not working . Yes Stand Only rownum , works but I would bring problems if the table is already full Because I have How to Increase ID

Comment: If `PA_ZMOVIMI_FACTURADAS` is empty, as indicated in the comments, then `MAX_ID` will be `null`. Any value added to `null` will result in `null`.

Comment: Also, creating IDs by adding to the maximum existing value is a terrible practice. I would strongly advise using a sequence to accomplish this.

Comment: @Allan - put your second comment as answer and I will rank it! It is definitely anti-pattern!

Comment: The mistake was what you mentioned me the null value. I have NVL but also not working so I placed a validation on the field if it had been placed no truth to 0. Thanks for the info!!